# Why my question is wrong or incorrect?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How to gather the url text inside HTML-div via regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55263440/how-to-gather-the-url-text-inside-html-div-via-regular-expression)

Why my question is wrong or incorrect?

Comment: There is no evidence of research of attempts to solve the problem, for example. Also, some commenters left feedback on why doing it that way was not a good idea.

Comment: Ask @Bobince - he knows [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) ;)

Comment: Regarding Tim's point, *"There's a risk you'd say "Thanks but I already tried that"*, note that answers that get this comment get down votes very quickly on new questions so that also makes people wary of answering questions that don't include what you tried.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I presume you are talking about the down-votes...

The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) states:

> Get answers to practical, detailed questions

Your question is a rehash of a question which is asked quite frequently and no research efforts have been shown or attempts have been provided.

Furthermore, the tour states:

> Don't ask about...
>
> - **Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)**
> - Product or service recommendations or comparisons
> - Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.
> - Anything not directly related to writing computer programs

and again, your question falls into one of the categories.

The title (tooltip) for the down-vote button shows:

> This question **does not show any research effort**; it is unclear or not useful

and once again, your question falls into that category too.

As of writing this, there a currently two close votes citing the following reasons:

> **Off-Topic Because** - Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

and

> **Too Broad** - Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

they should also provide an indicator as to why your question is being received negatively.

Answer (score 11):

Questions that show input and then ask folks who answer to write a regular expression for you are generally seen as impolite. While people do enjoy helping people with regex, asking folks to just do it for you is seen as presumptuous.

When you don't show people what you've tried, some unfortunate things happen:

- We don't know your skill level, so we don't know how much detail to put in an answer.
- We don't know how *you* understand the problem, so we don't really know what to put in a useful answer
- You *may* have been using the correct regex the whole time and there's some other problem with the input. There's a risk you'd say "Thanks but I already tried that" which would have wasted someone's time writing an answer.

If you simply don't know where to begin, *say so* and let us know what you searched, what didn't make sense in the results, etc - this helps folks give you an answer that teaches you something rather than code you can just copy and paste.

Without *some* sense of where you're stuck, we just don't know how to write the kind of answers that we like to write here (we'd prefer to teach instead of just giving someone something to paste). And the best way to show us where you're stuck is to show us what you've tried so far, or at least, what you searched for and why it didn't help.